# What's the right way to access sharepoint folders and files in C# using pnp.core and pnp.framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, sharepoint

I need to work with some files stored on the SharePoint folders on my c# application, but atm I can not find the right way to do that. I'm using Microsoft.sharepoint.client, pnp.core and pnp.framework as libraries and my code is something like:

```
            string DocLibrary = "Documents";
        
        try
        {
            using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
            {
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                List DocumentLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocLibrary);

                clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Title);
                clientContext.Load(DocumentLibrary);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                
                
                //part where I need to access the files
             

                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(exp.Message + Environment.NewLine + exp.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Let's say for instance that I need to access that the URL of the folder is "https://teamsite.msc.com/sites/mysite/Shared%20Documents/General/TestFolder/"
is there a way to access directly to the folder? Cause the only way I found to access this is by doing something like this:

```
                clientContext.Load(DocumentLibrary.RootFolder);
                clientContext.Load(DocumentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                
                FolderCollection fcol = DocumentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders;
                foreach (Folder f in fcol)
                {
                    clientContext.Load(f);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    If(f.name="General")
                         //iteration on folder and files
                    
                    
                }
```

And this approach as I know it's terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` to get the folder directly.

See [Working with folders and files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

Comment: Ok thank you now I can retrieve a folder, and even files with GetFileByServerRelativeUrl. But what's the correct way to read or write on a Sharepoint.Client.FIle. Probably it's a dumb question but I can not find much documentation about it.

Comment: The easiest would be File.SaveBinaryDirect. You don't need any Client.File with it, just the URL and the data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint (there are examples)